# WebGL2 rendering to R32F texture

Tags: webgl, webgl2, webgl-extensions

I can't bind `R32F` texture to `framebuffer`, because such textures are not "color renderable by default" according to [this source](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-data-textures.html).

But then it says "those features are available as optional extensions".

How to I use those extensions? How do I get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to enable the `EXT_color_buffer_float` extension

```js
function main() {
  const gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl2");
  const ext = gl.getExtension("EXT_color_buffer_float");
  if (!ext) {
    console.log("sorry, can't render to floating point textures");
    return;
  }

  const tex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  const level = 0;
  const internalFormat = gl.R32F;
  const width = 1;
  const height = 1;
  const border = 0;
  const format = gl.RED;
  const type = gl.FLOAT;
  gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat,
    width, height, border, format, type, null);

  const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(
    gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
    gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, level);

  const status = gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER);
  console.log(`can ${status === gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE ? "" : "NOT "}render to R32`);
}
main();
```